# Could someone show what a sample emacs .erc-auth.el file would look like?

Tags: emacs

[The ERC Manual](http://idlebox.net/2011/apidocs/emacs-23.3.zip/erc/erc_7.html) shows code for loading authentication information:

`(load "~/.emacs.d/.erc-auth")`

but does not show what that auth info would look like. I'd appreciate a sample file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have any particular format. It's just another file that can contain lisp code (you're giving it to `load`, after all). Taking a look at the code, I'm not really sure how you would use it to set a password for use on an irc server, but you could use it to set passwords for use with nickserv; see `erc-nickserv-passwords` in erc-services.el.

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.emacs.d/.ercrc.el`

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/.erc-auth")
```

And something like this in `~/.emacs.d/.erc-auth`

```
(setq erc-nick "my-id")  
(setq erc-password "my-pw")
```